# How to use where when using custom query in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my database application. I am not sure if it is possible to use get_where for custom query in codeigniter database class.

This is my query

```
  $this->db->query("select model, varient, (select color from mtbl_colors where mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles");
```

Now if i want to filter the above using where clause, I am using the query as

```
  function getVehicles($model='',$varient='')
 {
      if($model!='')
          {
            $q=$this->db->query("select model,varient,(select color from mtbl_colors where
            mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles 
            where model='$model'")->result();
            return $q;
           }
       elseif($varient!='')
          {
         $q=$this->db->query("select model,varient,(select color from mtbl_colors where
            mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles 
            where varient='$varient'")->result();
            return $q;
           }
    }
```

This is only an example, where i have to write all conditions for each where conditions. So, I may be missing some thing in codeigniter which can accomplish such multiple where conditions more easier than i am using right now.

EDIT::::

after suggestion from @Yan I tried as follows

```
 function getVehicles($where_clause='',$where_value='') {
    $sql = "select model,varient,(select color from mtbl_colors where
    mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles";
   $where_clause=array("varient", "model", "colorid");
   $where_value=array("MAGNA 1.4", "SANTRO", "3")

    if (!empty($where_clause) && !empty($where_value)) {
      $sql .= " where $where_clause = ?";
     return $this->db->query($sql, $where_value)->result();
    }
   return false;
  }
```

I received a database error saying "invalid column value Aarray"

as my intention was to implement multiple condition to generate results as per my filter options.

Comment: You can find about this in codeigniter documentation [http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "select model,varient,(select color from mtbl_colors where
        mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles";

$where_condition = '';
if (!empty($model)) {
    $sql .= " where model = ?";
    $where_condition = $model;   
}
elseif (!empty($varient)) {
    $sql .= " where varient = ?"; 
    $where_condition = $varient; 
}

if (!empty($where_condition)) {
   return $this->db->query($sql, $where_condition)->result();
}
return false;
```

Using this way escapes the input.

EDIT: 
A nicer solution but you need to sanitize the `where_clause` variable:

```
function getVehicles($where_clause='',$where_value='') {
   $sql = "select model,varient,(select color from mtbl_colors where
        mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles";

   if (!empty($where_clause) && !empty($where_value)) {
      $sql .= " where $where_clause = ?";
      return $this->db->query($sql, $where_value)->result();
   }
   return false;
}
```

EDIT 2 - Using an array:

```
function getVehicles($where_array) {
    $sql = "select model,varient,(select color from mtbl_colors where
        mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles";

    $values = array();
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($where_array as $key => $value) {
        if ($counter > 0) {
           $sql .= " AND ";
        }

        $sql .= " where $key = ?";
        array_push($values, $value);
        $counter ++;
    }
    return $this->db->query($sql, $values)->result();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yan Could you please help out if I can use multiple columns inside where_clause and multiple conditions inside where_value?


Just Now I tried using array but it didn't work

Comment: How can I use order by with this SQL??

Comment: Add to the `$sql` variable the `ORDER BY` command after the `foreach` loop and before the `return` statement.